# What is the difference between @import and @use in Dart Sass?

Tags: css, sass

What is the exact difference between @use and @import in sass(I think it's available in dart-sass)? If they're the same which one better to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All credits go to [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/introducing-sass-modules/).

> The new `@use` is similar to `@import`. but has some notable differences:
>
> - The file is only imported once, no matter how many times you `@use` it in a project.
> - Variables, mixins, and functions (what Sass calls “members”) that start with an underscore (_) or hyphen (-) are considered private, and not imported.
> - Members from the used file (buttons.scss in this case) are only made available locally, but not passed along to future imports.
> - Similarly, `@extends` will only apply up the chain; extending selectors in imported files, but not extending files that import this one.
> - All imported members are namespaced by default.

Comment: Thanks, the link is very useful :)